# All questions relating to tag not shown?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

When I search for the tag "conservation-biology" the preview states that 5 questions are using the tag ("conservation-biology × 5"). However, when I go to the tag site only one question is shown, and in the top right it says "1 question tagged". This is clearly wrong and I know of other questions that are also using the tag.

The same problem happens for other tags as well (have looked at e.g. "entomology" and "ecology").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just had a look at the tags you mentioned and can't seem to reproduce your problem:

[conservation-biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conservation-biology) shows 4 questions in the tag list and has 4 questions on the tag page.

[entomology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entomology) shows 59 questions in the tag list and has 59 questions on the tag page.

[ecology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecology) shows 43 questions in the tag list and has 43 questions on the tag page.

---

Are you definitely on one of the regular tabs for the tag page?  I.e. are you on the **newest**, **votes** or **active** tabs (which show all questions) rather than the *frequent* or *unanswered* tabs (which do not show all questions, only a subset).

Also check that you are not filtering between multiple tags, a search for `[conservation-biology][botany]` would only produce one result, for example.

I wont put this as [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) until you've got back to us because I can't reproduce the numbers you mention (5 and 1) for the conservation biology tag in any arrangement and can't see that any questions have been active recently for it to be a caching issue.  Perhaps you could try and see if the problem persists in incognito/private browsing mode or on a different computer.

Comment: Well, now I feel stupid. Yes I was on the "unanswered" tab. I just removed conservation-biology from an unanswered question, which is why you cannot reproduce the issue. Should I remove the Q from meta since it is a simple error on my part?

Comment: @fileunderwater no don't worry about it, you're not the first to query this and you definitely wont be the last :)